# PHP version compatibility check

Tags: php

How do I know my code which version of the language is compatible? Is there a way to figure out which is the minimum version of PHP language that can execute it without error? Maybe there is some Checker or a function, method, class?

Comment: There could also be a maximum version of PHP language that can execute it without error.

Comment: Ok but how to know his compatible?

Comment: Either you know your code well and you'll check each functions docu regarding PHP version or you simply run a syntax check on several servers with the versions you want to ensure compatibility

Answer (score 15):

Most likely you need to have different PHP versions installed. Then you can  check compatibility of your code with specified PHP version using shell:

```
find . -name *.php | xargs -n1 /usr/bin/php -l
```

`php -l` command runs PHP in syntax check only mode. The command above will check each PHP file in your project againts compatibility with PHP version located at /usr/bin/php.

Comment: I use localhost now. Is there any software to check whether my code is compatible with any version?

Comment: Or you can use a single command: `find . -type f -iname '*.php' -exec /usr/bin/php -l {} \;`

Comment: throws unknown primary or operator   find . -name '*.php' | xargs -n1 /usr/bin/php -l works on mac

Comment: Unfortunately it does not detect removed functions so it is of little use.

Answer (score 13):

Install the PHP version you want to test and run `php -l file.php` to test if the file passes the lint check. If PHP is unable to parse the file, it will tell you.

In general, you should be aware of which features became available in which version. Disregarding PHP 5.3 with its several patch versions that added significant improves for a moment, this boils down to knowing what features were brought with PHP 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0, and explicitly pointing to that version in your `composer.json`.

As a hint: 5.4 has short array syntax and traits, 5.5 has generators and `finally`, 5.6 comes with variadic functions and argument unpacking, and 7.0 has scalar type hinting and return types. It helps to use a IDE that knows about these features and warns you if you use something that isn't supported in the version you selected.

PHP comes with a constant `PHP_VERSION` that contains the current version you are running on, and has a function `version_compare()` to allow for easy comparing of version notation as in "which one is greater". This would allow to execute different parts of the code depending on the version, allowing to add compatibility layers for some things you need if you run on lower versions, and using the PHP implementation (usually faster) when running on more recent versions.

Apart from this, you will always stumble upon problems with extensions not being installed. This isn't a problem with the PHP version itself. PHP has `function_exists()` and `method_exists()` to detect if you can call something before you do (and fail with a fatal error). You can detect this error condition and either have a different solution, or inform the user he has to add something to his PHP installation.

I would recommend using Travis CI for open source projects. Basically you get it for free, and adding different PHP versions is like adding a new line in the travis.yml configuration file. They do offer plans for private repositories as well. Any other CI installation offering you plenty of PHP versions will also work as long as you are running your code on all the PHP versions you intend to support.

Final suggestion: Drop support for PHP 5.3 and 5.4. These versions are out of maintenance (or leaving security-only fix phase in 2 months from now) and shouldn't really be targeted anymore.

Comment: I have written classes now. Is there software that can scan them and say you are compatible or not at the localhost?

Comment: As I said: Install PHP in the version you want to check and run the `php -l` command to see if PHP can parse it.

Answer (score 12):

I used the [PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility](https://packagist.org/packages/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility) library to check my project's version compatibility, I recommend.

You can specify the version of PHP you want to check. For example, to test PHP 7.3:

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs -p . --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 7.3
```

Comment: The latest release of PHPCompatibility 9.3.5 was released on Dec 27, 2019 and does not detect php 8 code compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

https://3v4l.org/

This online tool shows your code output for more than 150 different PHP versions (every version released since 4.3.0) plus HHVM.

Not sure if it's enough for your purposes.

Comment: Very good resource. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The Docker provides the ability to follow a suggested by [pamelus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490289) proposal with a really small efforts:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v /path/to/your/app/src:/app php:8.0 bash
find /app -name '*.php' | xargs -n1 /usr/local/bin/php -l > /app/reportphp8
```

So `php:8.0` is a tag which can be obtained from [DockerHub page of PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated). By changing this version your can easily check your app's compatibility with 8.1/9.3/whatever version you want.

`/path/to/your/app/src` is a directory of your application sources root (the directory containing source code of YOUR application only, i.e. `src/` dir in Symfony and `app/` in Laravel. That's done to prevent checking syntax of the `vendors` dir).

The report will be stored in your application root named `reportphp8`.

### Important

The advice above is about the syntax only, i.e. it can detect whether you use removed or deprecated language structures or core functions. It won't be able to detect if you supply the correct types to functions having changed signature, etc. For those purposes use static analyzers like [Pslam](https://psalm.dev)/[PHPStan](https://phpstan.org)/[Phan](https://github.com/phan/phan).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to test your code for php 8.0 compatibility (slightly improved on https://odan.github.io/2020/12/22/php8-compatibility-check.html):

You cannot install PHPCompatibility from the release branch because the latest version was released before php 8.0 and is not compatible with it.

```sh
# install from development branch
composer require --dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer phpcompatibility/php-compatibility:dev-develop

# colorized output
phpcs --config-set colors 1

# test code in src dir
vendor/bin/phpcs src -p --report=code --ignore=vendor/* --standard=vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility/PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 8.0
```

Another way is to enable the logging of everything deprecated by setting `E_DEPRECATED` in the `php.ini` config.

```
; Development Value: E_ALL
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL
```