# measure the minimum php version of a project

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Well I write a lot of code and use a lot of functions, how can I check what is the current php version of my project..

So I can know what is the minimum php version required to run the project.

Comment: $version = phpversion();
print $version;

Comment: @Ranjeet Singh I want to check the minimum php version of my project not the real php version used by the server

Comment: Are you using any framework?

Comment: @Ranjeet Sing  iam using custom mvc framework

Comment: I think OP wants to determine what the minimum PHP version is that will correctly run his code. Ie. if he uses function X (PHP 5.3+) and Y (PHP 7) then the desired answer is: 7

Comment: @Kempeth Yes, thats what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in one click in PhpStorm, but you can set different PHP language levels (from lowest to highest (7.1 a.t.m.)) at File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP and then run Code > Inspect code.
Inspection results would show you if some code parts are deprecated or could be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Blatantly stolen from user pamelus [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490289/362432):

> Most likely you need to have different PHP versions installed. Then
>   you can  check compatibility of your code with specified PHP version
>   using shell:
>
> ```
> find . -name *.php | xargs -n1 /usr/bin/php -l
> ```
>
> `php -l` command runs PHP in syntax check only mode. The command above
>   will check each PHP file in your project againts compatibility with
>   PHP version located at /usr/bin/php.

Comment: It does not find removed functions, therefore of little use.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the boundaries. These are dictated by 3rd party libs you are using. In your `composer.json` keep reducing `"require": {"php": "=x"}`, until you get a conflict with one of the libraries, or manually check requirements for all libraries in `vendors`.
2. Check your code compatibility. Pick a base image from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/, and set up a project. Keep increasing php version in your Dockerfile form version defined in step 1, until you get linter happy with syntax, and unittests passed.

Or use https://travis-ci.org/ or similar to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[phpcompatinfo](http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo/manual/current/en/getting-started.html)** command line tool:

```sh
# Download the CLI tool:
wget http://bartlett.laurent-laville.org/get/phpcompatinfo-5.0.12.phar

# Analyse a project, output results to screen:
php phpcompatinfo-5.0.12.phar analyser:run path/to/project

# Or output the results to a file:
php phpcompatinfo-5.0.12.phar analyser:run path/to/project --output=compatinfo.log
```

Sample output - the very last line is the final result:

```
Data Source Analysed

Directories                                         11
Files                                               13

Extensions Analysis

    Extension Matches REF      EXT min/Max PHP min/Max PHP all
    Core              Core                 4.0.0       5.3.0
    PDO               PDO      5.1.0       5.1.0
    curl              curl     4.0.2       4.0.2
    intl              intl     2.0.0b1     5.3.7
    libxml            libxml   5.1.0       5.1.0
    openssl           openssl  5.2.0       5.2.0
    pcre              pcre     4.0.0       4.0.0
    spl               spl      5.1.0       5.1.0
    standard          standard 4.0.0       4.0.0       5.3.2
    Total [9]                              5.3.7

Namespaces Analysis

    Namespace                             Matches REF  EXT min/Max PHP min/Max PHP all
    +global                                       Core             4.0.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo                           user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Analyser                  user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Api                       user             5.3.0       5.3.2
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Api\V3                    user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Collection                user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Console                   user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Console\Formatter         user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Output                    user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\PhpParser                 user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Reference                 user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Util                      user             5.3.0
    Total [12]                                                     5.3.0       5.3.2

Interfaces Analysis

    Interface                                        Matches REF  EXT min/Max PHP min/Max PHP all
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Reference\ReferenceInterface 1       user             5.3.0
    Total [1]                                                                 5.3.0

No trait found

Classes Analysis

    Class                                                              Matches REF  EXT min/Max PHP min/Max PHP all
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Analyser\CompatibilityAnalyser                         user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Api\Reference                                          user             5.3.0       5.3.2
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Api\V3\Reference                                       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Collection\ReferenceCollection                 1       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Console\Application                                    user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Console\Formatter\CompatibilityOutputFormatter         user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Environment                                    4       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Output\Reference                                       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\PhpParser\ConditionalCodeNodeProcessor         1       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Reference\ExtensionFactory                     2       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Reference\SqliteStorage                        1       user             5.3.0
    Bartlett\CompatInfo\Util\Version                                   10      user             5.3.0
  U Bartlett\Reflect\Analyser\AbstractAnalyser                         1       user             5.3.0
  U Bartlett\Reflect\Api\BaseApi                                       1       user             5.3.0
  U Bartlett\Reflect\Api\V3\Common                                     1       user             5.3.0
  U Bartlett\Reflect\Console\Application                               1       user             5.3.0
  U Bartlett\Reflect\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter                 2       user             5.3.0
  U Bartlett\Reflect\PhpParser\NodeProcessorAbstract                   1       user             5.3.0
  U Doctrine\Common\Collections\AbstractLazyCollection                 1       user             5.3.0
  U Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection                        1       user             5.3.0
    PDO                                                                2       PDO  5.1.0       5.1.0
  U PhpParser\Node                                                     21      user             5.3.0
  U PhpParser\Node\Name                                                1       user             5.3.0
    RuntimeException                                                   1       spl  5.1.0       5.1.0
  U Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\TableSeparator                    3       user             5.3.0
  U Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface                   4       user             5.3.0
    parent                                                             5       Core 5.0.0       5.0.0
    self                                                               11      Core 5.0.0       5.0.0
    stdClass                                                           1       Core 4.0.0       4.0.0
    Total [29]                                                                                  5.3.0       5.3.2

Functions Analysis

    Function                    Matches REF      EXT min/Max PHP min/Max
    array_key_exists            7       standard 4.0.7       4.0.7
    array_map                   2       standard 4.0.6       4.0.6
    array_merge                 3       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    array_pop                   6       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    array_shift                 2       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    array_slice                 1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    array_values                1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    closure-73-75                       user                 5.3.0
    copy                        1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    count                       14      standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
 C  curl_version                1       curl     4.0.2       4.0.2
    defined                     4       Core     4.0.0       4.0.0
    dirname                     3       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    each                        2       Core     4.0.0       4.0.0
    end                         3       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    explode                     2       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    extension_loaded            1       Core     4.0.0       4.0.0
    file_exists                 2       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    function_exists             1       Core     4.0.0       4.0.0
    in_array                    10      standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    is_array                    1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    is_callable                 1       standard 4.0.6       4.0.6
    is_string                   10      standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    ksort                       3       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    ltrim                       1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    mkdir                       1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    phpversion                  2       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    preg_match                  2       pcre     4.0.0       4.0.0
    sha1_file                   2       standard 4.3.0       4.3.0
    sprintf                     26      standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    str_replace                 1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    strcasecmp                  4       Core     4.0.0       4.0.0
    stream_resolve_include_path 1       standard 5.3.2       5.3.2
    strpos                      2       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    strtolower                  1       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    substr                      2       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    sys_get_temp_dir            1       standard 5.2.1       5.2.1
    ucfirst                     5       standard 4.0.0       4.0.0
    version_compare             9       standard 4.0.7       4.0.7
    Total [39]                                               5.3.2

Constants Analysis

    Constant               Matches REF     EXT min/Max PHP min/Max
 C  INTL_ICU_VERSION       2       intl    2.0.0b1     5.3.7
    LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION  1       libxml  5.1.0       5.1.0
    LIBXML_VERSION         1       libxml  5.1.0       5.1.0
 C  OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER 1       openssl 5.2.0       5.2.0
 C  OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT   1       openssl 5.2.0       5.2.0
    PHP_EOL                5       Core    4.3.10      4.3.10
    PHP_VERSION            4       Core    4.0.0       4.0.0
    __DIR__                1       Core    5.3.0       5.3.0
    false                  14      Core    4.0.0       4.0.0
    null                   15      Core    4.0.0       4.0.0
    true                   10      Core    4.0.0       4.0.0
    Total [11]                                         5.3.0

Conditions Analysis

    Condition                       Matches REF     EXT min/Max PHP min/Max
    defined(INTL_ICU_VERSION)       2       intl    2.0.0b1     5.3.7
    defined(OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER) 1       openssl 5.2.0       5.2.0
    defined(OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT)   1       openssl 5.2.0       5.2.0
    function_exists(curl_version)   1       curl    4.0.2       4.0.2
    Total [4]                                                   5.3.7

Requires PHP 5.3.2 (min), PHP 5.3.2 (all)
```

Comment: Sounds like a great solution. I've installed and ran it. However, take a look at the example output (which is similar to mine: the "PHP min/Max" column displays only one value. That's pretty unlikely: most PHP scripts will run on a range of PHP versions. So, what does the number actually represent? And if it's the min version, how can we use this tool to find out the max?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a clear explanation of what the "/Max" part refers to. That value definitely shows the MINIMUM required PHP version.

Comment: Yep, OK. Thanks for confirming that. 

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is documented in the [phpduck website](http://phpduck.com/minimum-php-version-script/). Download the php file from the website, place it in the root of your project and run it to know the minimum version of PHP that your project can run on. It also lists the names of the functions used and links to the php manual.

Alternatively, you can just create a .php file and use the following PHP snippet in it.

```
<?php eval(file_get_contents("http://phpduck.com/resources/minVersion.condensed.php.txt")); ?>
```

Comment: Was gonna try this, but the link is broken, is there an alternative?

Comment: I'm not aware of any alternate.